# Rails Polymorphic Simple Form Collection Select - Pass Second Attribute Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a polymorphic model caled `sales_code` with `sales_codeable_id` and `sales_codeable_type` being the polymorphic attributes. The related models are `processors` and `platforms`.

I am generating an array of processors/paltforms in my `sales_code_controller` like so:

```
@processorsPlatformsArray = Processor.order(:name, 'id asc').map{|p| [p.name, p.id, p.class.name]}
@processorsPlatformsArray += Platform.order(:name, 'id asc').map{|p| [p.name, p.id, p.class.name]}
```

In my form (simple form) for creating new sales codes, I have the following input:

`= f.input :sales_codeable_id, collection: @processorsPlatformsArray, label: "Processor/Platform:", required: :true`

When I select a processor/platform from the drop down list, it successfully passes the appropriate sales_codeable_id into my form params. However, submitting the form throws an error, because a value is not being passed for the sales_codeable_type (obviously required). What is the most efficient way to pass the class name of the selected processor/platform as the sales_codeable_type param?

Answer (score 1):

Without JavaScript: You can use the `value_method` option on the input to construct a value that looks something like `object_type|id` and then parse that parameter manually in your controller

With JavaScript: Add a hidden input for `sales_codeable_type` to your form. When rending the collection, add an HTML data attribute to each option with the sales codeable type for that option. So it ends up looking like:

```
<option value="1" data-type="Processor">Processor 1</option>
```

Add a change handler to the select that populates the hidden field with the `data-type` attribute of the selected option.

In either case, the controller should probably whitelist the type values, validating that they are one of the two approved values.

A third approach that I have not tried yet would be to use `GlobalId` to find the associated object, like so: http://stefan.haflidason.com/simpler-polymorphic-selects-in-rails-4-with-global-id/

Comment: I ended up using a combo of the global id and assigning the params via parse in the controller. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!